# grunt.js reports that I have invalid utf-8

Tags: utf-8, gruntjs

I use Grunt for compiling SASS files.

It gives an error message:

```
Running " Sass : dist " ( Sass ) task
Warning: Error : Invalid UTF-8
Use --force to Continue .
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, grunt.js requires your input files to be encoded in UTF-8. Check that they are. I don’t know how you’re creating your SASS files, as you haven’t seen fit to tell us. If they’re created by hand in a text editor, check that the text editor is set to save files in UTF-8 encoding.

I don’t really understand why you’ve asked a question here. The error message says that your input files are not in valid UTF-8 encoding. So fix that. What’s the question?

Answer (score 0):

try running with the --verbose tag to get more info.

try running sass outside of grunt - grunt merely interfaces with the sass app.

its possible that there's an error with your grunt config or the files you're attempting to process